# Find value of cell next to searched cell?

Tags: python, list, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm trying to find the value for the cell NEXT to the cell I've found the value in. I have a column for tags and for links. If the link has a certain tag, the links value should be displayed. How can I do this in python with google-spreadsheet API?

I couldn't find a solution in the documentations.

```
ll = sheet.findall(topic)
    for i in ll:
        print(i.value)
```

How can I change it so it outputs the value of the column next to the cell?

Comment: Provide the input data and your expected output as well.

Comment: Yes, the more context you can provide the more likely it is someone will understand and answer the question. It looks like this might be about Excel data. Which Python package are you using to handle it? What does `sheet.findall` return? It sounds as though you want to show values from one column for all rows where another column has a certain property. Is this correct?

Comment: The simplest way is to collect the desired addresses from the list of gspread `Cell` that gets returned, and then request those values explicitly. Those addresses' values can be requested via the Sheets API or gspread.